# What are the different types of terminals and how can I find out what the current one is?

Tags: command-line, terminal

I want to automatically be put in a `screen` if I log in on a tty (if I'm using e.g. Terminal, I can simply open a new window instead.) I've already figured out the `screen` parameters and startup file configurations; I just need a reliable way to check whether the terminal is a tty, a terminal emulator, or something else. As far as I know, there are two main types of terminals: tty's (like the ones you can get to in Linux with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F#</kbd>) and terminal emulators (e.g. Apple Terminal, `xterm`, etc.)

What are the different types of terminals one is likely to encounter today, and how can I tell which kind the current session is in from a script?

(I have Linux and Mac systems, and I would like the test to work on both. If it requires a non-standard program, that should be available in the Debian, Ubuntu, and Homebrew repositories.)

Answer (score 0):

I know of two different types of (pesudo) terminals: tty and pts. ttys are the terminals reachable using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F#</kbd>. pts` are the terminals started inside gnome-terminal (or konsole if using kde, or xterm).

There is a command called `tty` which will tell you what terminal you are currently running on.

Output from running inside a gnome-terminal:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/2
```

Output from running in <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

```
$ tty
/dev/tty1
```

I do not know whether there are more types of terminals. Those two are the only ones I have encountered in my many years of using linux.

Here are more information about terminals:

- [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_(Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_%28Unix%29)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal

Comment: Ah…Macs seem to use a different system; I ran `tty` from a Terminal window and got `/dev/ttys002`.

Comment: So…should I just assume there are only tty's and emulator programs, and check that the output of `tty` matches `/dev/tty<number>`?